# Sorting objects by class, then name using d3

Tags: javascript, sorting, d3.js

I have an array of objects that I want to sort by the title, then by whether another property has a value or not. I'm trying to `d3.sort` but I don't think I'm doing it correctly. I've tried:

```
filtered.sort(function(a, b) {
        d3.ascending(a.claimed, b.claimed) ||
            d3.ascending(a.title, b.title);
```

As well as [a variation of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913538/d3-performing-sort-by-classes) to better fit my needs, but neither of them seem to be sorting correctly. Is there something I am missing?

Here is a sample of the data in the object that I access I am working with:

```
author: "String"
claimed: "String" //This should be sorted first
mapClass: "String"
name: "String"
tags: "String"
thumbnail: "URL"
timestamp: "Date"
title: "String" //Then this should be second
url: "URL"
```

Comment: You're missing a return statement. :-)

Comment: Also, I've never seen anyone use `||` in order to implement multiple sort keys. That's quite clever, although I usually have to write such code in Java, where that wouldn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just missing a return statement! This seems to work for me.

```
filtered.sort(function(a, b) {
  return d3.ascending(a.claimed, b.claimed) ||
      d3.ascending(a.title, b.title);
});
```

Comment: Gah! I can't believe I missed that. I guess that's what I get for staring at code for too long :)